# Visual Foxpro attempting to .click() a submit button on web or .submit() the webform - failing

Tags: button, click, submit, html, foxpro

I am programming in Visual Foxpro. I tried to programatically .click() at the submit button. It used to work, but now it triggers nothing. Alternatively I tried to .submit() the form. This too triggers nothing. But if I click the submit button at the website, it works perfectly. Can anyone help me out? arunkasi.co@gmail.com

My coding as as follows:

```
declare Sleep in kernel32 integer nmilliseconds

WebMain = CREATEOBJECT("InternetExplorer.application")
WebMain.navigate("https://epayment.hasil.gov.my/fpx/one.php")
WebMain.visible = .t.

DO WHILE WebMain.busy .OR. WebMain.readystate#4
   Sleep(300)
ENDDO

WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").jenis_id.selectedindex = 1
WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").no_id.Value = "123456781234"
WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").kapca.Value = "56789"
WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").cmdSubmit.click() && IT DOES NOT WORK !
WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").Submit() && ALTERNATIVELY, THIS TOO DOES NOT WORK !
```

Comment: Have you checked to be sure that the web page you're loading hasn't changed anything important, like the name of the LogonForm1?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause of your change in behavior is an update to Internet Explorer, wherein they improved the security model to keep malicious websites from injecting unwanted behavior into them.

See if the website you are attempting to reach has an actual web service that applications can use to send POST messages via HTTP instead of using a web page, (such as using the MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest object).  If that website is your company's, creating a proper web service is a far better use of time than automating internet explorer through FoxPro.

But, if that's not possible, I believe you can adjust your code to use the IE-specific [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536423.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter to click() or submit(). This will work:

```
WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").cmdSubmit.click(1) 
or
WebMain.Document.Forms("LogonForm1").Submit(1)
```